# Bootstrap 3. Center columns when middle column has a max-width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm trying to create a pretty basic layout with Bootstrap 3. I want one center column with a  max width and two outer columns to fill up the rest of the space and I want it all to be centered.

Without the max-width on the middle column, everything is centered nicely, but when I add the max-width, white space appears on the right forcing the rest of the layout off-center.

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/RFu17MmLXT) showing the issue.

Is there a way to do this using Bootstrap rows and columns?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To answer you last question: No. Not with bootstrap's rows and columns. I would use display:table et all and see if that works. You also want equal eights too, that is not possible out of the box either. Since it's not native to CSS, nearly all frameworks that I know of don't have a solution for it. JQuery can help a lot.

Comment: Here's a way to fake it, but the two side columns are the same color http://css-lab.com/demos/3col-fluid/3col-fix-cntr.html